# Get website directory listing in an R vector using RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm trying to get the list of files in a directory on a website. Is there a way to do this similar to the dir() or list.files() commands for local directory listing? I can connect to the website using RCurl (I need it because I need an SSL connection over HTTPS):

```
library(RCurl)    
text=getURL(*some https website*
,ssl.verifypeer = FALSE
,dirlistonly = TRUE)
```

But this creates an HTML file with images, hyperlinks, etc. of a list of files, but I just need an R vector of files as you would obtain with dir(). Is this possible? Or would I have to do HTML parsing to extract the filenames? Sounds like a complicated approach for a simple problem.

Thanks,

EDIT: if you can get it to work with http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeGencodeV7/ then you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

This is last example in the help file for getURL (with an updated URL):

```
url <- 'ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/'
filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)


# Deal with newlines as \n or \r\n. (BDR)
# Or alternatively, instruct libcurl to change \n’s to \r\n’s for us with crlf = TRUE
# filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, ftplistonly = TRUE, crlf = TRUE)
filenames = paste(url, strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]], sep = "")
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: For the ftp site that you mention, yes it works. But it doesn't work for sites such as: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeGencodeV7/

Comment: Dear @dag I got the following error while trying out the suggestion you gave
[here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187525/1972786)

`url <- 'ftp://XX.XX.XXX.XX/images/uploads_webapp/'

> filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to 54.251.104.13 port 21: Connection refused`

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra Thank you. I changed the URL now (almost two years after your comment, yes...)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   library(RCurl)

   dir_list <-
     read.table(
       textConnection(
         getURLContent(ftp://[...]/)
       )
     sep = "",
     strip.white = TRUE)
```

The resulting table separates the date into 3 text fields, but it is a big start and you can get the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading a [RCurl document](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf) and came across a new piece of code:

```
stockReader =
function()
{
values <- numeric() # to which the data is appended when received
# Function that appends the values to the centrally stored vector
read = function(chunk) {
con = textConnection(chunk)
on.exit(close(con))
tmp = scan(con)
values <<- c(values, tmp)
}
list(read = read,
values = function() values # accessor to get result on completion
)
}
```

followed by

```
reader = stockReader()
getURL(’http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/stockExample.dat’,
write = reader$read)
reader$values()
```

it says 'numeric' in the sample but surely this code sample can be adapted? Read the attached document. I'm sure you will find what you're looking for.

It also says

> The basic use of getURL(), getForm() and postForm() returns the contents of the requested document as a single block of text. It is accumulated by the libcurl facilities and
>   combined into a single string. We then typically traverse the contents of the document to
>   extract the information into regular data, e.g. vectors and data frames. For example, suppose
>   the document we requested is a simple stream of numbers such as prices of a particular stock
>   at diﬀerent time points. We would download the contents of the ﬁle, and then read it into
>   a vector in R so that we could analyze the values. Unfortunately, this results in essentially
>   two copies of the data residing in memory simultaneously. This can be prohibitive or at least
>   undesirable for large datasets.
>   An alternative approach is to process the data in chunks as it is received by libcurl. If we can
>   be notiﬁed each time libcurl receives data from the reply and do something meaningful with
>   the data, then we need not accumulate the chunks. The largest extra piece of information we
>   will need to have is the largest chunk. In our example, we could take each chunk and pass it
>   to the scan() function to turn the values into a vector. Then we can concatenate this with
>   the vector from the previously processed chunks.

Comment: after testing this function on sample link here is its error : `Error: unexpected input in "getURL(’"
>         write = reader$read)
Error: unexpected ')' in "        write = reader$read)"
> reader$values()
Error in reader$values : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`