# Error accessing ftp with getURL in R

Tags: r, url, download, ftp, rcurl

I want access files on the internet, but I get the following error message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Access denied: 530
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In strsplit(str, "\\\r\\\n") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

This is my code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699856/get-website-directory-listing-in-an-r-vector-using-rcurl):

```
library(RCurl)    
url<'ftp://ftp.address'
    userpwd <- "user:password"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd,
                    ftp.use.epsv=FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(RCurl)
filenames <- getURL(url="ftp://user:password@ftp.address",ftp.use.epsv=FALSE, dirlistonly = FALSE)
```